# AngularJs switch between 2 html body from route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

Suppose I have an app with 3 different page

Page 1 - template 1

page 2 - template 1

page 3 - template 2

page 4 - template 2

I want to use the same template for page 1 + 2 and same template for pagees 3 + 4.

So I thought about something like this:
on index.html I have

```
<body class="body" data-ng-show="is_index"></body>
<body class="body" data-ng-hide="is_index"></body>
```

and I'm setting the `is_index` from  `$routeChangeSuccess`

```
.controller('app', ['$scope','$route','$location',function($scope,$route,$location){
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function($currentRoute,$previousRoute ){

        if ($route.current.title == 'page1')
        {
            $scope.is_index = true;
        }
        else if ( $route.current.title == 'page2')
        {
            $scope.is_index = true;
        }
        else if ( $route.current.title == 'page3')
        {
            $scope.is_index = false;
        }
    });
```

Well this is not working,
I get the body loaded before is_index is set.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts how should I do it correctly.

Comment: You write your code in $routeChangeSuccess. So the two views load first then should be hidden.

Comment: Where are you declaring `ng-controller="app"`? body must be in scope of that controller for the hide/show to work

Comment: is_index should be the key to choose between body1 or body2, i didn't configure ng-controller cause i don't have controller for index.html

Comment: try the event `routeChangeStart` and see.

Comment: is there a better way to use 2 templates 2 different htmls and css some if that i can run on index.html in order to make the seperation?